# LaTeX or some other font package: Is there a built-in ICAO waypoint symbol

Tags: fonts, latex, gis, symbols

Looking for an easy way to plot these on a python geoaxis. They're typically represented as four-pointed stars with a circle cut out (fly-over waypoint) or the same, enclosed in a circle (fly-by waypoint). Obviously I can add these in post-processing, but that doesn't lend itself to batch jobs.  See for example:

[image: Waypoint Symbol Example]

Answer (score 0):

Using a UTF-8 white four-pointed star, ✧, U + 2727, was close enough.